# Как сделать чтобы текст не расползался?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы текст не расползался? фиксированная ширина span не помогает
Сделать абсолютную позицию тоже, ломается всё

```css
.footer-circle-button{
  background: #329370;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.footer-circle-button:hover{
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<button class="footer-circle-button">              
  <span class="btn_text">
    Ответы на часто задаваемые вопросы
   </span>     
</button>
```

Comment: вместо width height сделайте transform: scale (1.1)

Comment: спасибо, сработало всё)

Answer (score 0):

Используй margin

```css
.footer-circle-button{
  background: #329370;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.footer-circle-button:hover{
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<button class="footer-circle-button">              
  <span class="btn_text">
    Ответы на часто задаваемые вопросы
   </span>     
</button>
```